# How to return promise in case of multiple transactions?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to learn to work with firestore transactions.

Here is my code:

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(message);

    let mergedId = loggedUserId + toBeContactedUserId;

    let loggedUserRef = db.collection('users').doc(loggedUserId);
    let toBeContactedUserRef = db.collection('users').doc(toBeContactedUserId);
    let messageDbRef = db.collection('messages').doc();

    db.runTransaction((transaction) => {

      transaction.get(loggedUserRef)                        //First transaction
        .then(userDoc => {
          let userData = {
            ...userDoc.data(),
            contacts: {
              ...userDoc.data().contacts,
              [toBeContactedUserId]: {
                ...userDoc.data().contacts[toBeContactedUserId],
                lastMsg: message,
                unreadMsg: 0
              }
            }
          }
          loggedUserRef.set(userData);
        })

      transaction.get(toBeContactedUserRef)                    //Second transaction
        .then(userDoc => {
          let unreadMsgInc = userDoc.data().contacts[loggedUserId].unreadMsg + 1;
          let userData = {
            ...userDoc.data(),
            contacts: {
              ...userDoc.data().contacts,
              [loggedUserId]: {
                ...userDoc.data().contacts[loggedUserId],
                lastMsg: message,
                unreadMsg: unreadMsgInc
              }
            }
          }
          toBeContactedUserRef.set(userData);
        })

      transaction.get(messageDbRef)                           ////Third transaction
        .then(msgDoc => {
          messageDbRef.set({
            from: loggedUserId,
            to: toBeContactedUserId,
            content: message,
            reaction: false,
            seen: false,
            searchId: mergedId,
            time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
          })
        }
        )
    })
    .then(res=>{
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
  }
```

`handleSubmit()` is the function which is invoked upon clicking a button.
In the first `transaction.get()` I am doing a write operation. In the second `transaction.get()` I am doing a read and a write operation and in the third, I am doing a write operation.

When I am running the code I get error as: `Error: Transaction callback must return a Promise`

I am not clear if I am using transactions the right way. Is there a way I can write all this logic in a single transaction.get()

Please guide me on how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Promise.all` to wrap all three promises:

```
db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
  const p1 = transaction.get(loggedUserRef)
    .then(userDoc => {
      ...
    })

  const p2 = transaction.get(toBeContactedUserRef)
    .then(userDoc => {
      ...
    })

  const p3 = transaction.get(messageDbRef)
    .then(msgDoc => {
      ...
    })
  return Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]); // 
})
.then(res=>{
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err);
})
```

Alternatively, you can use `async` / `await` to have the compiler generate that for you and get rid of some of the nesting:

```
db.runTransaction((transaction) => async { // 
  let userDoc = await transaction.get(loggedUserRef);
  ...

  userDoc = await transaction.get(toBeContactedUserRef);
  ...

  const msgDoc = await transaction.get(messageDbRef)
  ...
})
.then(res=>{
  console.log(res);
})
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: In my above example I am defining three transactions. Due to some reason when a transaction does not complete it retries the operation. The problem I am facing is that my database is updated in every transaction retry. Have I missed something in my code? I only want to update only once. please help me with my problem.